# Unity Sprite Mirror Repeating

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite

I set spriteRenderer in Tiled mod also set sprite WrapMode to Mirror but when I changing width of sprite texture is repeating in normal mod and dont mirror in each repeat.
is there anything I missed ?!
Sprite in Scene:
[image]

Sprite Setting:[image]

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution, the mirror only works when you use tiling. To solve this problem, create an Unlit / Transparent material like the following and set its tiling to x: 2 and y: 1.

[image]

Now it is enough to give your sprite renderer the made material. And now your sprite is mirrored.

[image]

[image]